# Lightspeed database-first tables with plural and singular generating same entity names

Tags: c#, oracle, orm, database-first, lightspeed

I am using `Oracle` and `LightSpeed Orm` and generating model from database.

It seems there is an issue while creating tables that are both plural and singular.

I am getting an error `Error    2   Ambiguous moniker '/Ecom/ClaimType' encountered. It is used for both 'ClaimType' and 'ClaimType'.`

In this specific instance it's tables CLAIM_TYPE and CLAIM_TYPES that get same (ClaimType) entity generated.

**How do I generate two different entities for these?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This came back from lightspeed support:

> You will need to split this into two separate model files. We require
>   entities to be uniquely named in a single model.
>
> J.

(Which imho is ridiculous solution)